# Processing - cannot convert float to int

Tags: compilation, processing

I have a code like this:

```
    float[] x = {5,11,17,23,26,23,18,12,7,4,5,6,7,6,3,2,5,5,4,3,3,5,10,18,26,32,26,18,10,5,2,10,12,14,15,9,8,14,13,9,7,5,3,8,17,33,49,32,16,7,3,1,13,16,23,31,26,25,30,22,14,9,7,0,1,9,38,101,38,9,0,1,0,12,17,32,60,89,88,59,30,15,8,6,6,14,19,10,279,10,19,14,8,3,6,10,26,89,360,359,88,25,9,4,2,10,30,82,259,1000,260,82,32,13,5,5,9,26,89,358,359,89,26,9,4,3,6,13,19,9,280,9,20,14,8,3,11,17,31,60,89,89,60,31,16,9,6,0,1,9,38,102,38,9,0,1,0,12,16,23,30,25,25,31,22,14,10,7,3,8,17,33,50,33,17,8,3,1,9,11,13,14,8,9,15,13,10,7,6,5,10,18,27,33,27,18,11,6,3,5,6,6,6,2,3,6,6,5,4,1,5,11,18,24,27,24,18,12,7,3};

    void setup(){
    size(620,620);
    float k=1;
    float q=0;
    for (float j=0;j<height;j=j+30){
      if(k%2!=0){
        for(float i=30;i<width;i=i+60){
            fill(kolor(x[q]));
            rect(i,j,20,20);
            q=q+1;
        }
       k++;
      } else {
        for(float i=0;i<width;i=i+60){
            fill(kolor(x[q]));
            rect(i,j,20,20);
            q=q+1;
            }
       k++;
      }
     }
    }

    float kolor(float input){
          return map(input,0,1000,0,255);
    }
```

When I try to compile, I get "cannot convert float to int" error, connected with lines `fill(kolor(x[q]));`.

I tried changing this to `fill((int)kolor(x[q]));`.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What's the signature of fill command? also any reason for using array index as float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with line `fill((int)kolor(x[q])` is that `x` is an array, and you can only access array members by using ints, while you access it using `q` which is a float.

Try changing `float q = 0;` to `int q = 0;`

By the way, it looks like java code, is it java?

Comment: Processing is a lot like Java.

Comment: In fact it is Processing, but it is based on Java.
@klarki, you are genius, thank you very much! :)
After changing mentioned line everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using floats in the first place? You probably should be using ints, especially with the `%` in there.

[Here](https://processing.org/reference/fill_.html) is the signature of the `fill()` command, for those interested.